# Handle click event of element returned by Pipes with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-pipe

I'm using Ionic 3 with Angular 5 and I want to handle the click event of an element returned by Pipes. I've the following code:

`linkify.ts`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'linkify',
})
export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {

    return value.replace(/@([a-z0-9_.]+)/gi, "<span class='link'>@$1</span>");
  }
}
```

`post.html`:

```
<ion-card-content>
    <p [innerHTML]="post.content | linkify"></p>
</ion-card-content>
```

So, when `post.content` has this content:

```
Hello, @StackOverflow! I'm @Igor
```

Turns to:

```
Hello, <span class='link'>@StackOverflow</span>! I'm <span class='link'>@Igor</span>
```

However, I want to handle the click event in `span` element, so, I tried:

```
return value.replace(/@([a-z0-9_.]+)/gi, "<span class='link' tappable (click)='openPage($1)'>@$1</span>");
```

But I get the following message on console:

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

I've added `DomSanitizer` on `linkify.ts`:

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value.replace(/@([a-z0-9_.]+)/gi, "<span class='link' tappable (click)='openPage($1)'>@$1</span>"));
```

And I've added too the `openPage` function in both the `post.ts` and the `linkify.ts` (in both to check if event is fired):

```
openPage(link) {
    console.log(link);
}
```

But nothing happens. The only thing I noticed is that when I click on the element it receives the class "activated", that is, the Angular is detecting the event, but it is not firing the function.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Have you find a way to get it work?

Comment: @calebeaires yes. I kept the pipe and created a HostListener on my component: `@HostListener("click", ["$event"]) onClick(e) {if (e.target.classList.contains("link")) console.log(e.target);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finnally I found a way to get it work. Kept the Pipe and created a `HostListener` on my component:

```
@HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("link")) console.log(e.target);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify the solution? Keep the click where it belongs, and only pipe the small thing. Pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe {
  transform(value: string) {
    return `@${value}`;
  }
}
```

Gets a string, retuns a string.

And your component template:

```
<span class='link' (click)="go(whatever) [innerHTML]="'StackOverflow' | myPipe"></span>
```

And the component also implements the `go()` method so everything is in it's place. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-49367076?file=app/hello.component.ts)'s how it works.

Comment: Alternatively DomSanitizer again. I just think you messed the scopes there.

Comment: But, in the way you suggested, all the element would react to the click event, and I just want the `@mentions` to react. I'm using dynamic content so I have no way to set the "name" element as you do, so I'm using Pipe to detect the `@mention` and convert it. Please correct me if I am wrong.